# oracle sub query or union

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a **case** table as follows:

| caseId | caseType | last_name | first_Name | aCaseStatus | bCaseStatus | created_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P | test | a | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | M | test1 | b | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | M | test2 | c | 1 | 3 | 1 |

**aCaseStatus**

| id | descr |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa |
| 2 | bbb |
| 3 | ccc |

**bCaseStatus**

| id | descr |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | xxx |
| 2 | yyy |
| 3 | zzz |

I have a query like below

```
select c.case_id caseId,  c.last_name lastName, c.first_name firstName,

 caseType  caseType,

acaseStatus||','||bCaseStatus as caseStatus

from cases c

 join aCaseStatus acs

on acs.id = c.aCaseStatus

 left outer join bCaseStatus bcs

on bcs.id = c.bCaseStatus

where (c.created_by = 1 ) and ( c.aCaseStatus in (1) or c.bCaseStatus in (0)) and c.caseType='M'
```

UI has a display like below

| caseId | Name | caseStatus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | b,test1 | aaa, yyy |
| 3 | c,test2 | aaa, zzz |

When you look at the UI display `caseStatus` is a combination of `aCaseStatus`, `bCaseStatus`.

Also, the UI table has a search functionality wherein `caseStatus` is a multi-select dropdown field.

This dropdown has a combination of `aCaseStatus` and `bCaseStatus`.

Dropdown is as below:

```
CaseStatus

aaa

bbb

ccc

xxx

yyy

zzz
```

Note: aCaseStatus alone is a mandatory field so I have given an inner join, however, `bCaseStatus` is not so I have given a left outer join.

When the user selects `aaa`, UI should display:

| caseId | Name | caseStatus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | b,test1 | aaa |
| 3 | c,test2 | aaa |

when the user selects `aaa`, `xxx` UI should display:

| caseId | Name | caseStatus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | b,test1 | aaa, xxx |
| 3 | c,test2 | aaa |

But when I use the above query for `aaa` selection I get:

| caseId | Name | caseStatus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | b,test1 | aaa, xxx |
| 3 | c,test2 | aaa |

I do not want the xxx to be displayed even though caseId has xxx `caseStatus`. How should I change the query to achieve this? Should I write a union query one for `aCaseStatus` and the other for `bCaseStatus` or is there any other way this can be achieved?

Suggestions, please?

Comment: next time please format your tables properly.

Comment: how big are the tables ??

Comment: Case table is big